# How do I define an object variable structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, definition

I want to define something like the following object structure, so I can populate it from a number of sources. What statements do I need to define it?

`Offices[]` is an open-ended array as is `rel[]` underneath it. All the elements are strings or maybe numbers.

```
Offices.name
Offices.desc
Offices.rel.type
Offices.rel.pt
```

Comment: Well you may want to start with a reference about basic JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First I would make `Offices` an array:

```
var Offices = [];
```

Then populate that with objects:

```
var obj = {
    name: "test",
    desc: "Some description",
    rel: []
}

Offices.push(obj);
```

Now you have your array (`Offices`) populated with one object, so you could access it via `Offices[0].desc` -- you can also populate the `rel` array with `Offices[0].rel.push(anotherObj)`

Answer (score 3):

If i understand correctly, you want to place multiple objects of the same type inside the Offices array. In order to easily build multiple objects of the same type you could use a constructor:

```
function Office(name, desc, rel){
  this.name = name;
  this.desc = desc;
  this.rel = rel;
}
```

Now you can declare an array to hold instances of the above type:

```
var offices = [];
```

And you can add new instances like this:

```
offices.push(new Office('John', 'good guy', []));
```

You can apply the same idea to the rel array to enforce the structure of the objects, or simply use object and array literals:

```
offices.push(new Office('John', 'good guy', [{ type : 'M', pt : 3 }, { type : 'Q', pt : 2 }]);
```